# Can i convert SQL Server 2012 import wizard into general SQL query?

Tags: sql

I want to convert sql server import wizard into normal query or tell me the sql query for importing csv file to the database.

Comment: Please show what efforts you have made.

Comment: I'm very new to this field of BI, i have assigned a task that i should import csv files from outside into the database with SQL Query. So, if u know the trick pls help.

Answer (score 0):

you need a conversion here, look at following to get some possible help:

http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm

Comment: assalamualaikum usman, i dont need a tool. I need a corresponding SQL Query to do this. Anyhow thank u for the reply